# How can I detect what game a User is playing on discord and write the aktivity in a .txt by c#

Tags: c#, discord

I tried to write a bot that reads the activity of a discord user or me and writes it to a txt file.
Unfortunately, with userID he never finds any other users except himself (Bot) and with UserName he doesn't find anyone at all. Any further input is somehow not possible.

thats the last code

```
    private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task OnReady()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Bot ist eingeloggt als {_client.CurrentUser.Username}");
        _timer.Change(0, (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalMilliseconds);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object state)
    {
        _ = Task.Run(async () => await CheckAndLogStatus());
    }

    private async Task CheckAndLogStatus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the username whose activity you want to check:");
        string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();

        if (ulong.TryParse(inputUsername, out ulong userName))
        {
            var user = _client.GetUser(userName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                string activityName = user.Activities.FirstOrDefault()?.Name ?? "Now activity found";
                string statusMessage = $"Aktivity of the User ({user.Username}): {activityName}";
                string statusMessageFormatted = $"%Game%{activityName}%Game%";

                Console.WriteLine(statusMessage);
                Console.WriteLine($"Write in file: {statusMessageFormatted}");

                File.WriteAllText($@"D:\.....\LastApp.txt", statusMessageFormatted);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User not found. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid user name. Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
```